# Gatling scala Kafka avro : schema.registry.url ' were supplied but are not used yet

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, avro, gatling, scala-gatling

I am using a script to serialize and deserialize Avro messages using Gatling. I have taken this script from @tinkoff on GitHub.

While running it, I get the following error:

```
schema.registry.url ' were supplied but are not used yet
```

The following is the script I'm running:

```
package ru.tinkoff.gatling.kafka.examples

import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.{KafkaAvroDeserializer, KafkaAvroSerializer}
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.{Deserializer, Serde, Serializer}
import ru.tinkoff.gatling.kafka.Predef._
import ru.tinkoff.gatling.kafka.actions.KafkaRequestReplyActionBuilder
import ru.tinkoff.gatling.kafka.protocol.KafkaProtocol
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

class AvroClassWithRequestReplySimulation extends Simulation {

  // default serde for unknown classes is avro serde
  // schemaRegUrl must be specified if custom avro scheme is used, when the send method requires implicit
  implicit val schemaRegUrl: String = "http://localhost:9094"

  // example if you want to use your own or custom serde
  val ser =
    new KafkaAvroSerializer(
      new CachedSchemaRegistryClient("schRegUrl".split(',').toList.asJava, 16),
    )

  val de =
    new KafkaAvroDeserializer(
      new CachedSchemaRegistryClient("schRegUrl".split(',').toList.asJava, 16),
    )

  implicit val serdeClass: Serde[MyAvroClass] = new Serde[MyAvroClass] {
    override def serializer(): Serializer[MyAvroClass] = ser.asInstanceOf[Serializer[MyAvroClass]]
    override def deserializer(): Deserializer[MyAvroClass] = de.asInstanceOf[Deserializer[MyAvroClass]]
  }

  // protocol
  val kafkaProtocolRRAvro: KafkaProtocol = kafka.requestReply
    .producerSettings(
      Map(
        ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG                   -> "1",
        ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG      -> "localhost:9093",
        ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG   -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
        ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG -> "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer",
        // schema registry url is required for KafkaAvroSerializer and KafkaAvroDeserializer
        "schema.registry.url"                        -> "http://localhost:9094",
      ),
    )
    .consumeSettings(
      Map(
        "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9093",
      ),
    )
    .timeout(5.seconds)

  // message
  val kafkaMessage: KafkaRequestReplyActionBuilder[String, MyAvroClass] = kafka("RequestReply").requestReply
    .requestTopic("request.t")
    .replyTopic("reply.t")
    .send[String, MyAvroClass]("key", MyAvroClass())

  // simulation
  setUp(scenario("Kafka RequestReply Avro").exec(kafkaMessage).inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(kafkaProtocolRRAvro)

  case class MyAvroClass()

}
```

I tried multiple ways but I'm getting the same error. Kafka and the Schema Registry are running fine locally.

I verified that all URLs are correct but I'm still getting same error.